# "An access token is required to request this resource" - Facebook graph API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I'm trying to use the facebook Graph API in my android application to retrieve the last posts from a Facebook Page. I have everything set up, so I can login with any account and even make a "/me" request to get the user's basic info. But when I try to make this request:

```
new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
    "PokerNewsBrazil?fields=posts&fref=ts/posts",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

             /* handle the result */

            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();
```

I receive the following error: "An access token is required to request this resource". 
But my access token exists and it is valid, because if I use the access token from the same session in the Graph API Explorer I receive a succesfull response containing the posts from that page.
Where am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change `HttpMethod.GET` to `HttpMethod.POST`.

This error arises because the SDK posts the access token behind the scenes, while the API is looking for it in a GET parameter.

For some reason using `HttpMethod.GET` and appending the access token to the url string causes various malformed access token errors.

I also encountered various errors when batching requests. If you encounter such errors, try executing a request standalone and debug from there.

The Facebook SDK is iterating relatively quickly yet the documentation is lacking and not up to date. Stick with it.